# Toggle html() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So my plan is to have a h4 tag so that when clicked in displays my container div and changes the text to say "hide form". When the user clicks the text again the form hides and the text changes back to "show form". I have the div itself animating correctly but the text is giving me an issue. When I click it initially it correctly changes to "Hide form". But when clicked again, the div hides but the text stays at "hide form". Ive tried multiply variants of using the if statement and employing the $(this) selector but no luck. Has to be in Jquery, not vanilla JS.

```js
$('.wrapper').hide();

var state1 = "Submit Details";
var state2 = "Hide form";

$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $('.wrapper').slideToggle(1000);

  if ($('#toggle').html(state1)) {
    $('#toggle').html(state2);
  } else if ($('#toggle').html(state2)) {
    $('#toggle').html(state1);
  }

});
```

```html
<header>
  <h3> Ajax Project </h3>
  <h4 id="toggle">Submit Details</h4>
</header>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think you're doing something wrong, is the line `if($('#toggle').html(state1))` meant to compare the div's HTML to the state1 variable?

Comment: @Phiter Yes correct

Comment: @AlonEitan the JS posted is in the js/main.js file

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(this).text($(this).text() == state1 ? state2 : state1)`

Note: Use `.text()` and not `.html()` since there is no reason to change the HTML when it's actually the HTML you want to change.

It will change your text according to the desired result.

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $('.wrapper').slideToggle(1000);
  $(this).text($(this).text() == state1 ? state2 : state1);
});
```

- `this` <-- refers to the object we are doing something with`('#toggle')`
- `$(this).text() == state1` <-- is basic a question. Is the `text` equal the value of `state1`.
- `? state2 : state1` means what to do if our question is true or falls. So if true use `state2`, else use `state1`

**Demo**

```js
$('.wrapper').hide();

var state1 = "Submit Details";
var state2 = "Hide form";

$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $('.wrapper').slideToggle(1000);
  $(this).text($(this).text() == state1 ? state2 : state1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <h3> Ajax Project </h3>
  <h4 id="toggle">Submit Details</h4>
</header>
<div class="wrapper">
  <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
awdawdaw
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, working perfect now! I've never seen this kinda line of code before, do you mind just telling me how it works? What is the thought process of it

Comment: @Cian Sure, give me a few sec to update the question

Comment: @Cian Take a look how, hope it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare your variables `state1` and `state2`

## Look at this code snippet

```js
$('.wrapper').hide();

var state1 = "Submit Details";
var state2 = "Hide form";

$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $('.wrapper').slideToggle(1000);

  if ($('#toggle').html() === state1) {
    $('#toggle').html(state2);
  } else if ($('#toggle').html() === state2) {
    $('#toggle').html(state1);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <h3> Ajax Project </h3>
  <h4 id="toggle">Submit Details</h4>
</header>
<div class="wrapper">
  <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">

  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just set the HTML and not check what is the current state.

Not that I would do it like this myself, but it answers your problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/u0bg7gb2/

```
$('.wrapper').hide();

var state1 = "Submit Details";
var state2 = "Hide form";

$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $('.wrapper').slideToggle(1000);

  if($('#toggle').text() == state1)
  {
    $('#toggle').text(state2);
  }
  else 
  {
    $('#toggle').text(state1);
  }

});

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ajax Project | Cian Tiernan</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h3> Ajax Project </h3>
      <h4 id="toggle">Submit Details</h4>
    </header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">

      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```